# if statement apparently not working in rsyslog

Tags: configuration, rsyslog

I'm trying to use the [RainerScript syntax](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_filter.html) in my Debian `/etc/rsyslog.conf` file.  I want to log daemon stuff to a particular file, but only from `pppd`.  Here's what I added:

```
if $programname == 'pppd' then {
    daemon.*;local2.*   -/var/log/pppd.log
}
```

I then restarted the rsyslog service.  Stuff does get logged to this file; however I also get stuff from `named` so the `if` statement either seems to be being ignored, or always evaluating to true.  Why would either of these be?  Have I made a mistake in the code?

Comment: You have mixed syntax going on there.

Comment: How is it mixed syntax?  Check out the RainerScript tutorial I linked to on the official rsyslog website; it says you can put the old syntax inside the new if clause syntax.

Comment: I believe I had tried the mixed syntax and it also failed for me in the past, I avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if $programname == 'pppd' and $syslogfacility-text =='daemon' and $syslogfacility-text == 'local2' then /var/log/pppd.log
if $programname == 'pppd' then ~
```

Line 1 says log to file /var/log/pppd.log

Line 2 says "OK stop logging to files", as in no further log files, the tilde actually means "discard".

Comment: But that's not quite doing what I want; it's not including the conditions that the facility be `daemon` or `local2`.

Comment: Updated the answer with conditionals for facility. Wasn't clear what you were trying to do with the syntax above.

Comment: OK so basically it simply seems the mixed syntax doesn't work, even though the documentation on the official rsyslog site says that it should.  :-)

Comment: That's what I have experienced!